# Doctor Who CYOA book where Gallifrey is a refugee camp

Tags: story-identification, doctor-who, choose-your-own-adventure

I'd like to identify this *Doctor Who* book that I read in what must have been the late 80s or early 90s.

It was nominally a choose-your-own-adventure story, but with not many choice points -- there were long segments of linear prose between them.

The protagonist ("you") was a savage, born in a caldera.

There is some kind of galactic disaster ongoing, and Gallifrey is being used as a refugee camp.

Involved in this disaster somehow is a "dimensional dust" which, when it escapes its container, causes spacetime (and the matter in it) to distort in unpredictable ways.

At some point (possibly a losing ending) the protagonist consumes some kind of sedative from a globule from a filigree box.

At some point, the protagonist is in a disused museum, in which "guide wands" of some sort were provided.  Visitors would carry these with them while walking through the museum; pointing the wand at an artefact would cause the wand to start speaking, telling the visitor details about the object.

I don't recall which incarnation of the Doctor was in it (barely remember him in the story at all, in fact), but most likely it was the 6th.

Comment: One of these; https://gamebooks.org/Search?SearchQuery=Doctor+who&SearchType=Title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the ['Make Your Own Adventure'](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Make_Your_Own_Adventure_with_Doctor_Who) gamebook *[The Garden of Evil](https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/cloister/gardenevil.htm)* by David Martin.

Several reviews mention that Gallifrey is acting as a relocation base for refugees

> You are psychic jungle boy who's found your way to a rescue-effort mounting Gallifrey, where refugees from across the universe awaiting relocation are about to riot. You and the Doctor need to uncover the links between the circumstances that led here, magical space dust, a mechanical religion and a garden on a sun before it's too late.